# Integrate Microsoft Outlook labels in PHP application

Tags: php, api, sharepoint, active-directory, exchange-server

I've no idea where to start. My request is to point me at the right direction and provide me some keywords to help searching for solution. Forgive me the most probably inaccurate terminology I'll be using here - I'll try to explain the problem descriptively.

In Microsoft Outlook and SharePoint, users' names are preceded by this ball showing their online/away/whatever status:

[image: MSO user's label]

The user's name is a hyperlink. When one points mouse cursor over the name, a label with more details pops up:

[image: MSO user's details]

I guess there's an API to handle this. How to implement that behavior into a PHP application? What API to use? Has the API a total-beginner guide?

---

EDIT:
I want to replicate Outlook's functionality. I'd like the PHP app to display the same user's details label as Outlook and SharePoint do. The PHP app is working in the same intranet where Outlook and SharePoint. I'm hoping to find the information in the same source where Outlook and SharePoint do.

---

EDIT2:
Retagged following the comments in hope to find more relevant source of information.

Comment: Can you please clarify some points: What information are you trying to get (i.e. name, email address) and where are you hoping to find this information? A database, a Microsoft Exchange server, LDAP etc?

Comment: Do you simply want to replicate the same UI/functionality *as Outlook has* in your PHP app, or does your question have something to do with Outlook *technically*?

Comment: You'll need to consult your network admin / IT guy responsible for these systems as the data source can and will vary network to network. It's probably going to be some combination of MS-SQL, LDAP/Active Directory or some other proprietary database and even then I don't believe there is a nice easy API you can hook in to for this sort of thing. Microsoft don't make things that easy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this status is analyzed from the Exchange calendar where you set your availability to something like

- Mon-Fri
- 08.00-12.00
- 13.00-17.00

At times outside that scope you/the user will be considered as unavailable. Also, times when you are booked in meetings will be considered as unavailable. Thats my assumption in this answer.

Now, there are a very well built web service api in exchange and how you would like to integrate this is up to you, but... I'd say that it will be quite complicated to build this in PHP.

I would have built the logic for this in a separate web service (WCF or ordinary web service) and keeping the logic in .net, this service should be able to communicate with php over SOAP and have specialized methods that are simple for PHP to handle. In example, send username and date, return availability for that day as xml or json.

- Exchange Web Services Reference
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119(v=exchg.140).aspx
- Sample: Get Calendar Data Using Exchange Web Services (C#) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2009/11/24/sample-get-calendar-data-using-exchange-web-services-c.aspx

Thats one way, if you want to go over sharepoint there is this http://www.bendsoft.com/downloads/sharepoint-php-tools/

Cheers.

**=== Edit ===**

There are methods to retrieve availability from the Exchange web services, GetUserAvailabilityRequest and (ofcourse) GetUserAvailabilityResponse

- [GetUserAvailabilityRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563800%28v=exchg.140%29)
- [GetUserAvailabilityResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563496%28v=exchg.140%29)

Note! Check the differences between 2010 and earlier versions of exchange, my references are to 2010